# Conda env inaccessible after installing virtualenv

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I have (almost) exactly the same question as this resolved question:

[How to solve the issue of the conflict of anaconda and virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221144/how-to-solve-the-issue-of-the-conflict-of-anaconda-and-virtualenv)

..but my problem is the inverse. Namely, I had been working with conda environments fine before (for science projects), but when developing web projects I installed virtualenv. Since then, my conda environments are unreachable with the source command.

Here are my conda envs:

```
| => conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
bunny                    /Users/.../anaconda/envs/bunny
root                  *  /Users/.../anaconda
```

The answer in the posted question, says I should change my current Anaconda path in bash_profile from :

```
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin
```

So, by changing this I thought running this command to the anaconda envs folder would work:

```
source /Users/.../anaconda/envs/bunny/bin/activate
```

The result is the virtualenv *`(env)`* gets activated, even if I am not on the directory where I installed it, which is:

```
/Users/./././WebDevelopment/DeployedProjects/./env
```

So I guess that the virtrualenv "source" command is masking the conda "source" command and works even if no absolute path is given:

```
| => source activate
(env) _______________________________________
| ~ @ Pablos-MBP 
| =>
```

Also on my `bash_profile` I have no path to virtualenv (like I do for anaconda)

How can I *"create an alias to the virtualenv that calls it with an absolute path to the activate script"* instead of calling it every time I use "source activate"?

Any help with this much appreciated!!

Best,

Pablo

PS. For reference, this answer also did not do the trick: [Conda virtual environment not changing...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863720/conda-virtual-environment-not-changing-under-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `source` is a shell command, unrelated to virtualenv and anaconda..

Comment: Thanks for the note @thebjorn . Not really sure what was causing the problem, but a simple update of conda did the trick:

| => conda update conda

After the update, my old virtualenv is now not accessible as I feared, but I created a new conda env with the requirements for my web development projects and all is working. I can deploy as per usual via conda and now also access my old conda envs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is of help to others, for completion, I will outline the steps that I took.

After re-installing Anaconda and losing access to my previous virtualenv for web development, I abandoned virtualenv and moved my web development work to my Conda environments. Basically, I needed to (re)source the necessary paths.

My steps were the following:

Note: the "..." in paths are my username on MacOS.

1. Create a new conda environment called "*webdev*", having python=2
2. Downloaded the [google-cloud-sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads) and moved (manually) the entire folder to the "*webdev*" bin folder like:

   ```
   /Users/.../anaconda/envs/webdev/bin/google-cloud-sdk
   ```
3. cd to that folder and run:

   ```
   ./install.sh
   ```
4. Make sure PATHs in nano .bash_profile are linked. On terminal:

   ```
   $ cd

   $ nano .bash_profile
   ```
5. Enter the following paths (first one should be there from Anaconda):

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH

   export PATH=/Users/.../anaconda/envs/webdev/bin/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc:$PATH
   export PATH=/Users/.../anaconda/envs/webdev/bin/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc:$PATH
   export PATH=/Users/.../anaconda/envs/webdev/bin/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH
   ```
6. Re-start the terminal. Enter the two commands in the terminal:

   ```
   source /Users/.../anaconda/envs/webdev/bin/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc

   source /Users/.../anaconda/envs/webdev/bin/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
   ```

After that this command should work:

```
 dev_appserver.py ./
```